# Unix concatenate two line if shorter

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I have 500k line of fix length data, but in some line there is enter character in between data.

Eg. Each line length is 26 character.

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOUPQRSTUVWXTZ
ABCDEFGHIJKLM<BR>
NOUPQRSTUVWXYZ
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOUPQRSTUVWXTZ
```

Line 2 is having enter character. I Want to remove enter character from line 2 and combine it with line below it.
E.g.

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOUPQRSTUVWXTZ
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOUPQRSTUVWXYZ
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOUPQRSTUVWXTZ
```

I tried to use awk and sed but result is not correct

Comment: please post accurate examples. these aren't all 26 characters wide. perhaps wrap the examples in backticks (upper left on your keyboard).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show us your best attempts in sed and awk, and explain how they fail.

Comment: Do you actually have the 4 characters `<BR>` in your file, or are you just trying to illustrate a newline?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Perl in your system, you can simply do this.

```
$ perl -pe 's/<BR>\n//' your_file_name
```

It is a one-liner. You simply run it at your command line.

Or with awk:

```
awk '{ORS = sub(/<BR>/,"") ? "" : "\n"; print $0}' your_file_name
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'N;s/<BR>\n//;P;D' file
```

or:

```
sed -z 's/<BR>\n//g' file
```

Answer (score 0):

One, slightly off-the-wall, way of doing this is to:

- remove all existing linefeeds
- insert new linefeeds every 27 characters

That looks like this:

```
tr -d '\n' < YOURFILE | fold -w 27   
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOUPQRSTUVWXTZ
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOUPQRSTUVWXYZ
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOUPQRSTUVWXTZ
```